# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Tags: linux, ssh

When I ssh, I get the prompt

```
[host@sma1 ~]$ ssh -Y c00
host@c00's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
host@c00's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
host@c00's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You must use keys for auth or specify login, as I understand.

For keys:

```
$ ssh -Y c00 -i /path/to/keys
```

For another login name:

```
$ ssh -Y login@c00
```